# Как получить токен с помощью Retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit, token

**Интерфейс OAuthServerIntf.class:**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("authorize?response_type=token")
Call<OAuthTokenYandex> requestTokenForm1(
         @Field("client_id") String client_id
);
```

**А вот buider, что в нем не так?**

```
 @NonNull
    public static OAuthServerIntf yandexBuilder() {
        //Using Default HttpClient
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("https://oauth.yandex.ru/")
                .build();
        OAuthServerIntf webServer = retrofit.create(OAuthServerIntf.class);
        return webServer;
    }
```

**Логи**

```
The call refreshTokenFormCall failed
                                                                                  java.io.IOException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at path $
                                                                                      at com.squareup.moshi.BufferedSourceJsonReader.syntaxError(BufferedSourceJsonReader.java:1094)
                                                                                      at com.squareup.moshi.BufferedSourceJsonReader.checkLenient(BufferedSourceJsonReader.java:990)
                                                                                      at com.squareup.moshi.BufferedSourceJsonReader.doPeek(BufferedSourceJsonReader.java:374)
                                                                                      at com.squareup.moshi.BufferedSourceJsonReader.peek(BufferedSourceJsonReader.java:202)
                                                                                      at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter$1.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:65)
                                                                                      at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:33)
                                                                                      at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiResponseBodyConverter.convert(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:32)
                                                                                      at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiResponseBodyConverter.convert(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:23)
                                                                                      at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:117)
                                                                                      at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
                                                                                      at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:106)
                                                                                      at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
                                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос , посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: В ошибке сказано `Use JsonReader.setLenient(true)` - т.е. что-то не так с преобразованием `json`. Думаю, надо смотреть что такое `MoshiConverterFactory`

Comment: Я так понимаю там проблема в конвертере. А как исправить?

Comment: Ну, по идее, как в ошибке и сказано, добавить `setLenient(true)` в билдере оного

Comment: А если вместо моши gsonfactory?

Comment: Может поможет, а может и нет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58161/discussion-between---and-).

Comment: Нет, в чаты я не хожу)

Comment: А вы не знаете как для яндекса билдер создать?

Comment: Нет, ни разу не пользовал. Надо в первую очередь смотреть доку чтобы понять что в ответе приходит. Может там не JSON а перенаправление куда-нибудь.